# What TLS and SSL protocols should I have turned on

Tags: protocols

I am using Explorer as my browser.  What do I have to have on regarding the TLS and SSL protocols.  There are several of each one.

Comment: Until someone gives a real answer, visit https://www.howsmyssl.com/ and see what happens

Answer (score 7):

Enable all of the versions that can be enabled (preferably, TLS 1.0 and higher), and then let the order of preference to the server.

Since you're using Internet Explorer, go to the [Internet advanced settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-vista/change-internet-explorer-advanced-settings) and enable the following according to your version:

- Internet Explorer 6: Enable TLS 1.0
- Internet Explorer 7: Nothing to do. TLS 1.0 is enabled by default.
- Internet Explorer 8-10: TLS 1.0 is enabled by default. Enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2
- Internet Explorer 11: Nothing to do. TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 are enabled by default.